# Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported

Tags: r, json, shiny, ggplotly, r-plotly

Please find below a reproductible example to explain my issue (I am using manipulateWidget R package which is directly related to Shiny R package):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(manipulateWidget)
library(data.table)


my_data <- data.table(
  DAT_RLV = as.POSIXct(c("2017-01-20","2017-01-21","2017-01-22",
                         "2017-01-23","2017-01-24")),
  VOL_CSO = c(0,4,3,4,2))


graphe_conso <- ggplot(data = my_data)+
  geom_line(aes(x = DAT_RLV,y = VOL_CSO),colour = "darkgreen")+
  labs(x = "Date", y ="my_values")

graphe_conso <- ggplotly(graphe_conso)
```

For now, everything is fine. Here is what I get:

[image]

Then I want to use this chart as a Shiny object:

```
manipulateWidget::combineWidgets(graphe_conso)
```

All dates on my x-axis have been converted to another format and I get the following warning:

[image]

Here is what I obtain on my x-axis:

[image]

Any tips would be appreciable to overcome this issue, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

It gets solved apparently when converting the POSIXct column to numeric and multiplying by 1000.
Then in the `ggplotly` command you have to specify that the x-axis is of type "date".

Then it appears correct and the `Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE)`-error disappears. But I actually don't know exactly why. There is obviously some bug with Date/POSIXct columns.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(manipulateWidget)
library(data.table)

my_data <- data.table(
  DAT_RLV = as.POSIXct(c("2017-01-20","2017-01-21","2017-01-22",
                         "2017-01-23","2017-01-24")),
  VOL_CSO = c(0,4,3,4,2))

my_data$DAT_RLV <- as.numeric(my_data$DAT_RLV)*1000
graphe_conso <- ggplot(data=my_data)+
  geom_line(aes(x = DAT_RLV, y = VOL_CSO, group = 1))+
  labs(x = "Date", y ="my_values")
graphe_conso <- ggplotly(graphe_conso) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(type = "date"))
manipulateWidget::combineWidgets(graphe_conso)
```